# Create arc between two CGPoints and get CGPoints along it

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift2

I want to display images on an arc between two points. I have a starting CGPoint and an ending CGPoint. I've seen answers for something like this using SceneKit and other answers that produce entire arches and graphs. I'm just working within a regular view.

My end goal is to end up with something like this (where letters represent images):

[image]

And I need to know where to set the center for B & C.

```
let firstLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(12, 200, 50, 50))
let lastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(250, 360, 50, 50))
```

Comment: Have you looked at using maths to calculate the locations?

Comment: @Wain I'm not sure how, I need it to be dynamic between A-D. Sometimes there can be a varying amount of elements.

Comment: Are you familiar with the parametric equation of a circle? It involves the center, radius, sin and cos. This is more a mathematical than a programming question.

Comment: @Martin R - some of that sounds vaguely familiar from high school lol. - I had a thought of using a corner radius on a UIView but I'm not sure how to isolate the quarter that I need and get it's CGPoints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you probably need parametric equation of ellipse rather than circle. It looks like this:

> x = *a*cos(t)*    y = *b*sin(t)*, where 0<=t<=2π

*a* and *b* are ellipse's radiuses. If we take that A is (x1, y1) and D is (x2, y2), n - number of points you wish between A and D (2 in your example - B and C) then point calculation should look something like this:

```
let a = x2 - x1
let b = y2 - y1
let angleStep = M_PI_2 / Double(n + 1)
var angle = angleStep
var points: [CGPoint] = []
while angle < M_PI_2 {
    let x = a * CGFloat(cos(angle))
    let y = y2 - b * CGFloat(sin(angle))
    points.append(CGPointMake(x, y))
    angle += angleStep
}
```